# extends of the class with private constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Suppose we have the following code:

```
class Test {
    private Test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}

public class One extends Test {

    One() {
        System.out.println("One");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new One();
    }
}
```

When we create an object `One`, that was originally called the parent class constructor `Test()`. but as `Test()` was private - we get an error.
How much is a good example and a way out of this situation?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is no way out. You have to create an available (`protected`, `public` or default) super constructor to be able to extend `test`.

This kind of notation is usually used in utility classes or singletons, where you don't want  the user to create himself an instance of your class, either by extending it and instanciating the subclass, or by simply calling a constructor of your class.

When you have a `class` with only `private` constructors, you can also change the `class` to `final` because it can't be extended at all.

---

Another solution would be having a method in `test` which create instances of `test` and delegate every method call from `One` to a `test` instance. This way you don't have to extend `test`.

```
class Test {
    private Test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    public static Test getInstance(){
        return new Test();
    }
    public void methodA(){
        //Some kind of implementation
    }
}

public class One {
    private final Test test;
    One() {
        System.out.println("One");
        test = Test.getInstance();
    }

    public void methodA(){
        test.methodA();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new One();
    }
}
```

Comment: The method `getInstance()` of class `Test` should be static. Otherwise it is not possible to make a call like `Test.getInstance()`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor of `test` non-`private` or move `One` into `test`.

BTW, your sample code contains a few issues:

- classes should be named title case (`Test` instead of `test`)
- I'd suggest to make the `One`'s constructor `private` unless it is called from a different class in the same package

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I found there is a way out. Like this:

```
class Base {
    private Base() {

    }

    public void fn() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }

    public static class Child extends Base {
        public void fn() {
            System.out.println("Child");
        }
    }

    public static Base getChild() {
        return new Child();
    }
}
```

Now, you can use getChild() to get instance of the extended class.

Comment: This only works when placing a static inner class because private methods are accessible to inner classes. Unfortunately, this doesn't help, because if you are able to change the class you are much better served by setting the constructor to protected or public in the first place..