# How do I make a third-party class public?

Tags: java

How do I make a third-party class public? Is there a way? any hacks?

Basically I what to extend the functionality of a class which i don't own. I can see the source but don't want to hack the original source and re-compile it.

thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to change the source, if you have it? Also, make sure you aren't violating any copyrights with whatever approach you take.

Comment: There is no clean solution anyhow. When the class is not public, the creator is free to change (or even remove) it in the next release. So the best answer is probably: Find a different solution for what you want to achieve! One alternative was already recommended: Grab the source code and recompile it. A better one could IMHO be: Grab the source code, and define it as a new class (in a new package), but **make sure not to violate any licenses**. If this is not possible (e.g. when the class requires other classes in the original package), then this is another reason for not doing it at all...

Comment: I assume this isn't nested?

Comment: What you mean as third-party class public? is a nested class? is a top-level class with default-protected visibility? or it has private constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the class isn't nested and is a top-level class (which is actually `public` with a `private` constructor), just create a `public` wrapper class and have method calls into an instance of that class with a `private` constructor. A similar [answer can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952820/2591612).

Comment: How do you make calls to the private class when it's private?

Comment: @OrangeDog: You get an instance of it

Comment: And how do you do that if it's private?

Comment: @OrangeDog: I imagine it's actually like this : `class Test { private Test() {} }`

Comment: @OrangeDog: He didn't say nested, so I am assuming it is a top-level class. Java doesn't allow top-level classes to be private.

Comment: They did say it's in 3rd-party code and he doesn't want to edit its source.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Right, so I assume (I think rightly) that it's not a nested class within his class. If it's within a public class third-party class and thus nested, then that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to change the modifier to public.

Comment: Not if you want to 'extend' it you can't.

Comment: Is using reflection really simpler than just recompiling the source, which the OP has access to?

Comment: @NickHolt well, the topic asks how to make it public. Anyhow, the 'extend' part will be tricky save for some bytecode manipulation, which isn't quite that simple..

Answer (score 0):

Using java reflection is best way to do it although I think what you want is you want to access a field or method and here is how you can do it using java reflection:

```
////you main class which does the magic
package mytest;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Member;

public class Testing {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Person c = new Person();
            try {
                Field f = Person.class.getDeclaredField("a");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Integer i = (Integer)f.get(c);
                System.out.println(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
}
///here is another class for this test called person
package mytest;

class Person {
    private Integer a =6;
}
```

Comment: He has the source, so decompiling isn't necessary.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I agree with you 100%, reflection is the best solution here I updated the answer based on your feedback. Thanks

Comment: He has the source, so wouldn't simply editing the source be the best solution?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for pointing this out. I'm telling multi-tasking is not good for me. I modified it again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways:

1. Using [byte code manipulation](http://asm.ow2.org/) (fast but a bit more complex)
2. Using reflection (slower but simple)
3. Decompile the class, make it public and recompile. Basically that's what byte code manipulation does on-the-fly