# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project XXXXX:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am looking for any help. I am trying to run a spring-boot project using mvn spring-boot:run and it is giving me the error on the screen shot. Take a look at the screenshots and also the full stacktrace that i have added under the screen shots.

It is not starting at all, as we can see here on the caused by "`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [C:\Intellij-Workspace\mobile-app-ws\mobile-app-ws\target\classes\com\assegd\app\ws\controller\UserController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression 'null'`
    " it seems like it is not creating a bean for the userController.

[image]

[image]

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\jbr\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Intellij-Workspace\mobile-app-ws\mobile-app-ws "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51897:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.3.4 spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.assegd.app.ws:mobile-app-ws >-------------------
[INFO] Building mobile-app-ws 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ mobile-app-ws >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ mobile-app-ws ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ mobile-app-ws ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ mobile-app-ws ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Intellij-Workspace\mobile-app-ws\mobile-app-ws\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mobile-app-ws ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ mobile-app-ws <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ mobile-app-ws ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-05-14 14:31:33.288  INFO 7668 --- [           main] c.assegd.app.ws.MobileAppWsApplication   : Starting MobileAppWsApplication on DESKTOP-K2HGC11 with PID 7668 (C:\Intellij-Workspace\mobile-app-ws\mobile-app-ws\target\classes started by aAsfaw in C:\Intellij-Workspace\mobile-app-ws\mobile-app-ws)
2020-05-14 14:31:33.291  INFO 7668 --- [           main] c.assegd.app.ws.MobileAppWsApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-14 14:31:34.746  INFO 7668 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-14 14:31:34.839  INFO 7668 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 86ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-14 14:31:35.285  INFO 7668 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-14 14:31:35.289  INFO 7668 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-14 14:31:35.292  INFO 7668 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@1e1b061' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-14 14:31:35.293  INFO 7668 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-14 14:31:35.299  INFO 7668 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-14 14:31:35.818  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
2020-05-14 14:31:35.829  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-14 14:31:35.830  INFO 7668 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-05-14 14:31:35.963  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/mobile-app-ws]           : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-14 14:31:35.964  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2609 ms
2020-05-14 14:31:36.011  INFO 7668 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-14 14:31:36.114  INFO 7668 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-14 14:31:36.120  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2020-05-14 14:31:36.314  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-14 14:31:36.383  INFO 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-05-14 14:31:36.564  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-14 14:31:36.691  INFO 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-05-14 14:31:37.458 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table addresses (id bigint not null, address_id varchar(30) not null, city varchar(15) not null, country varchar(15) not null, postal_code varchar(7) not null, street_name varchar(100) not null, type varchar(10) not null, users_id bigint, primary key (id))
2020-05-14 14:31:37.466 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table authorities (id bigint not null, name varchar(20) not null, primary key (id))
2020-05-14 14:31:37.467 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table password_reset_tokens (id bigint not null, token varchar(255), users_id bigint, primary key (id))
2020-05-14 14:31:37.467 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table roles (id bigint not null, name varchar(20) not null, primary key (id))
2020-05-14 14:31:37.468 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table roles_authorities (roles_id bigint not null, authorities_id bigint not null)
2020-05-14 14:31:37.469 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table users (id bigint not null, email varchar(120) not null, email_verification_status boolean not null, email_verification_token varchar(255), encrypted_password varchar(255) not null, first_name varchar(50) not null, last_name varchar(50) not null, user_id varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
2020-05-14 14:31:37.469 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table users_roles (users_id bigint not null, roles_id bigint not null)
2020-05-14 14:31:37.470 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
2020-05-14 14:31:37.472 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table addresses add constraint FKr9ce5hb61hmpvm107ccip0irl foreign key (users_id) references users
2020-05-14 14:31:37.478 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table password_reset_tokens add constraint FK52orwg09uutvs35oup693qjae foreign key (users_id) references users
2020-05-14 14:31:37.480 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table roles_authorities add constraint FKe4pjsn2c2ttg8bpbe1yk29snn foreign key (authorities_id) references authorities
2020-05-14 14:31:37.482 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table roles_authorities add constraint FKcj918h3ee3qad1xwbx4jvvcgc foreign key (roles_id) references roles
2020-05-14 14:31:37.484 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table users_roles add constraint FKa62j07k5mhgifpp955h37ponj foreign key (roles_id) references roles
2020-05-14 14:31:37.487 DEBUG 7668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table users_roles add constraint FKml90kef4w2jy7oxyqv742tsfc foreign key (users_id) references users
2020-05-14 14:31:37.489  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-14 14:31:37.496  INFO 7668 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-14 14:31:38.000  WARN 7668 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [C:\Intellij-Workspace\mobile-app-ws\mobile-app-ws\target\classes\com\assegd\app\ws\controller\UserController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression 'null'
2020-05-14 14:31:38.002  INFO 7668 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-14 14:31:38.006  INFO 7668 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-14 14:31:38.010  INFO 7668 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-05-14 14:31:38.012  INFO 7668 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-05-14 14:31:38.019  INFO 7668 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-14 14:31:38.028 ERROR 7668 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [C:\Intellij-Workspace\mobile-app-ws\mobile-app-ws\target\classes\com\assegd\app\ws\controller\UserController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression 'null'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.assegd.app.ws.MobileAppWsApplication.main(MobileAppWsApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression 'null'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.createPostInvocationAttribute(ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.java:79) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.java:96) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor$MethodSecurityMetadataSourcePointcut.matches(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:135) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:252) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:289) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:321) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:126) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'comma(,)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:135) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:52) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:43) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.createPostInvocationAttribute(ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.java:68) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.848 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-14T14:31:38+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project mobile-app-ws: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please try to select "mobile-app-ws" on the left panel - will it show more info?

Comment: Thanks @y.bedrov I have updated my question with the new screen shot. please take a look at it and let me know what u suggest me.

Comment: @Assegd Could you please attach full stacktrace ? that will it us to understand your issue. I found similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52811994/10553411 please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @Ganesh Thorat
   i have updated my question and added the full stacktrace under the screenshots. Please take a look at it and let me know.

Comment: did you find any answer to your question?

Comment: @Barttttt
it has worked for me from the terminal side using the mvn commands