# Why we cannot inherit a class with the private constructor in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, private

Why we cannot inherit a class with the private constructor in Java? Can anyone explain with simple example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extends of the class with private constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952815/extends-of-the-class-with-private-constructor)

Comment: You can extend a class with a private ctor: it just has to be defined in the same compilation unit. https://ideone.com/UXCpXr

Comment: And just for the record: please dont forget about accepting an answer at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Any `private` thingy within a class is **only** accessible from within that class. To any other class, even subclasses, it is like that private thing doesn't exist.

So, when your **base** class has **only** a private constructor, the child class simply couldn't make any kind of call to a super constructor. Because there is no such constructor that is visible to the child class.

Like:

```
class Base {
  private Base() { }
  static Base newInstance() { return new Base(); }
}
```

class Child extends Base {
   ...

There is no valid way to write give `Child` a constructor. Because any constructor has to call a super constructor. Of course, **if** `Base` had a non-private constructor, then the derived class has some `super()` it can call.

Comment: What is the reason child class constructor has to compulsory call parent class constructor?

Comment: The Java Language spec that says so. Think about it: a child object is also **always** a "base class object". It has all the fields from base, too. So, all these fields must be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If it has *only* private constructors, you can't call them from a subclass. A subclass is required to call one of the parent class's constructors, but it can't because they're not visible. Even if you don't explicitly call a parent class constructor there's still an implicit call to `super()`, which fails if the default constructor is private.

```
class Parent {
    private Parent() { }
    private Parent(int param) { }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    // Invalid: Implied call to super(), which is private.
    Child() { }

    // Invalid: Cannot call super(int) since it's private.
    Child() { super(42); }
}
```

Comment: Why is it required to call parent class constructor?

Comment: The same reason you can't create an object normally without calling a constructor. Constructors ensure objects are initialized correctly. If a subclass didn't call the parent's constructor the parent object might not be in a valid state.

Comment: Why not make parent's private constructor available to its children then?

Comment: They wouldn't be private, then; they'd be protected. Protected methods are part of a class's API contract and can't be changed without risking breakage of client code. Private methods can be changed, added, and deleted freely without any such worry.